# Get all posts that have NO terms with WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a wordpress loop, and I want to get all the posts that have NO terms assigned to them. Is there an easy way to do it? Or do I really have to get all the term ID's and do an tax query like this :

```
// Get all the term id's
$terms = array();
$terms = getAllTheTerms();

// Create an arguments which get all the posts that do not have a term with any
// of the id's.
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' =>
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $terms,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This seems like a stupid query because database wise it would be very easy to get all the posts without a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' =>
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => '',
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array('fields'=>'ids')); /* GET ALL TERMS FROM A TOXNOMY */
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $terms,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN' /* DO THE MAGIC -  Get all post that no in the taxonomy terms */
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Add some more clarification to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The question was: "I am writing a wordpress loop, and I want to get all the posts that have NO terms assigned to them. Is there an easy way to do it?"

Here is the answer: the following code replaces the code of the original poster and demonstrates the best solution.

```php
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ],
    ],
];
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: No idea why this solution was flagged by the commenters above. The code snippet is taken from the code example provided by the original poster (since that is what they requested help with), and has been modified to provide the correct solution.